# How to install LuaMetaTeX to MikTeX on Windows 11?

Tags: luatex, plain-tex, format

On GitHub you can find the Plain and LaTeX format for LuaMetaTeX. I am a Plain LuaTeX user and would like to switch to Plain LuaMetaTeX for some reasons. Examples: unpacking the contents of `\left` and `\right` and the new differential mathclass.

https://github.com/zauguin/luametalatex

But I do not understand how it is installed.

> Obtain luametatex from ConTeXt, drop the binary into the same location
> where your luatex binary is installed and copy (or sym-link) the file
> luametalatex.lua into the same directory.

- What binaries? Is it `luametatex.exe`?

> Then install luametalatex into your texmf tree by running l3build
> install in this repository.

- Sorry... What is that?

I understand really nothing of that...

Could someone explain the whole istalling process in words that are understandable for a Windows user, please?

Comment: That github is a highly experimental (usually non functional) setup for latex it includes a similarly experimental plain format (mainly for testing) it assumes you have luametatex already installed from context. There is no documentation or source for building formats for luametatex, so that github is reverse engineering and exprimental builds, you can not expect any end user documentation,

Comment: As the author of that repository I can only strongly support what David said: It's highly experimental, there is no documentation and I would strongly advice anyone who is not very experienced with setting up formats to stay away from it for now. On Windows it's even worse since it's completely untested there and the math support is rather limited right now.

Comment: It's not really possible to use Plain with LuaMetaTeX right now unless you're willing to do _a lot_ of work. Unlike other TeX engines, LuaMetaTeX has no backend (DVI/PDF output), no font code (Metafont/Type 1/OpenType), and no file finding code (like kpse). All of this is implemented in Lua for ConTeXt, but you'd need to either copy the ConTeXt code or implement it yourself to get a functional Plain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment installation with MikTeX is not supported, so if you want to use plain LuaMetaTeX on Windows you need to install TeX Live first.

Assuming you have TeX Live installed you can follow the following steps:

- Download the latest LuaMetaLaTeX source code from GitHub at https://github.com/zauguin/luametalatex/archive/refs/heads/trunk.zip and extract in into a directory on your system. (If you have git installed you can also clone the repository instead)
- Open the extracted luametalatex-trunk directory in a command line window, e.g. by opening it in Windows Explorer and doing a right click and selecting "Open in Terminal".
- Run `l3build install`.
- If this succeeds then the Lua support code is installed but you still need LuaMetaTeX (in the right version) and some platform specific support code. Download the installer from https://lmltx.typesetting.eu/installer-win64.zip and extract it. Then run `installer.exe`. I would recommend to run it from a command line window in order to allow seeing potential error messages, but it should also work if you run the program directly.

If these commands are successful then LuaMetaLaTeX is installed. You can try to use it by compiling you TeX files as normal, but instead of running `luatex` you run `luametaplain`.

You are likely to encounter many issues, feel free to report them at https://github.com/zauguin/luametalatex/issues.

Comment: Thank you, it really works! :) `luaotfload` and `luapstricks` are useable.